# linux merge only subset of lines from multiple files

Tags: linux

I have the following folder structure:

```
/drive1/180204_somerandomtext/file.csv
/drive1/180504_somerandomtext/file.csv
/drive1/190101_somerandomtext/file.csv
/drive1/190305_somerandomtext/file.csv
...
```

Each file.txt has the same structure, but contains different data. From a file.txt I want to extract only a subset of lines using the following command:

```
grep -A5000 -m1 -e 'Sample_ID,' /drive1/180204_somerandomtext/file.csv | tail -n+2
```

This command works and prints the next 5000 lines following the line that starts with 'Sample_ID,'

I've extended this command

```
grep -A5000 -m1 -e 'Sample_ID,' /drive1/180204_somerandomtext/file.csv | tail -n+2 | sed 's/^/180204_somerandomtext,/'
```

Using the 'sed' I now add to the beginning of each line the pattern '180204_somerandomtext', which is actually the name of the folder that contains the file.csv

I'm now stuck at the following steps:

- how to do this for all file.csv files in the subfolders of drive1
- how to store this result in one large file called 'samples.csv'

I've tried something with xargs. It works with the grep command, but piping the sed, isn't working then.

```
find /drive1/ -maxdepth 1 -name '1*' | cut -d '/' -f2 | xargs -I {} grep -A5000 -m1 -e 'Sample_ID,' /drive1/{}/file.csv | sed 's/^/{},/'
```

Comment: Piping won't work, because then you're essentially doing a `cat`. Put the command in a bash script, and then use `find`'s `-exec` to call it on every single file, it has found.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not a big fan of `xargs`, I'm finding `find -exec` much clearer to use, let me explain:
Imagine I would like to do something with a file `file1.txt`:

```
Command -sw1  param1 -sw2 param2.1 param2.2 file1.txt
```

Launch a command, and use switches `sw1`, `sw2` with parameters `param1`, `param2.1` and `param2.2`.

When I want to perform this for all `file1.txt` within a directory structure, I do the following:

```
find . -name "file1.txt" -exec Command -sw1  param1 -sw2 param2.1 param2.2 {} \;
```

So I just put the `find` command (with some information on where and what to find), and afterwards comes the `-exec`. After that `-exec` I put the exact command, where I replace my original filename by `{}` and I end the whole thing by `\;`.

In your case, it would be something like:

```
find /drive1 -name file.csv -exec grep -A5000 -m1 -e 'Sample_ID,' {} \;
```